# Crash when unwrapping optional

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, option-type

I have several clients that are complaining of a crash in my app. I have never been able to reproduce it. Crashlitics has detected the crash :

```
func addDevice(unconfiguredDevice: UnconfiguredDevice) {

    if let macSegment = unconfiguredDevice.macSegmentFromSSID { <<-CRASH
        print("unconfigured mac: \( macSegment )")

        if let setupDevice = self.unconfiguredDevices.value.first(where: { Device in Device.macEnd == unconfiguredDevice.macSegmentFromSSID! }) {
            setupDevice.unconfiguredDevice = unconfiguredDevice
        } else {
            self.unconfiguredDevices.value.append(SetupDevice(unconfiguredDevice: unconfiguredDevice))
        }
    }
}
```

The crash type is EXC_BREAKPOINT. I have seen on several other threads around here that this kind of crash might be related to optional unwrapping, and indeed that macSegment method there returns an optional. But I don't understand what the problem might be. (BTW this method is for detecting devices that are configurable via WAC).

Any ideas/tips/suggestions ?

Comment: Is `UnconfiguredDevice` an implicitly unwrapped optional? If it is, you should mark it with a `?`: `if let macSegment = unconfiguredDevice?.macSegmentFromSSID {`

Comment: You are try to forcefully unwrap nil value. problem goes here unconfiguredDevice.macSegmentFromSSID!

Comment: UnconfiguredDevice is returned by WAC .. I don't think that it is optional.. how ever that macSegment is a extension method that returns an optional.

Comment: @user426132 There should not be a crash line, you are pointing in your question. Check crash point again. Crash line you are pointing is correct and crash free.

Comment: That's the line indicated by crashlitics . I don't believe it to be the correct line.

Answer (score 0):

The crash occurs because `macSegmentFromSSID` was nil when you tried to unwrap it.
try like

```
if let setupDevice = self.unconfiguredDevices.value.first(where: { Device in Device.macEnd ==  macSegment}) {
            setupDevice.unconfiguredDevice = unconfiguredDevice
        }
```

Comment: That's what I think too... but do to the reproducibility of the crash (0 on my side) I will need to release a test version and see what the beta testers say .

Comment: @user426132 hmm okk.

Comment: @user426132 what if you do like this: 
if unconfiguredDevice.macSegmentFromSSID != nil {//other code goes here.
let macSegment = unconfiguredDevice.macSegmentFromSSID
}

Comment: @AravindAR According to code, shared by OP in its question, super block of `if-let` takes care of `macSegmentFromSSID` is nil or not. If it is nil then nested block/code won't execute. Yes, OP should write a code you've shown here, in your answer but I think your solution may doesn't make any sense. (Not providing a solution of crash)